# Unable to connect web-socket client in Android locally

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io, okhttp

We are trying to implement webSocket in android, the connection never established. but this is working fine with react-native, any can help us on the same thanks.

even I tried with socket.io and okHttp3, I may missed some configuration.

Here is my MainActivity file

```
package com.example.client_app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import tech.gusavila92.websocketclient.WebSocketClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebSocketClient webSocketClient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createWebSocketClient();
}

private void createWebSocketClient() {
    URI uri;
    try {
        // Connect to local host
        uri = new URI("ws://192.168.21.133:8080");
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    webSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
        @Override
        public void onOpen() {
            Log.i("WebSocket", "Session is starting");
            webSocketClient.send("Hello World!");
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextReceived(String s) {
            Log.i("WebSocket", "Message received");
            final String message = s;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
    //                            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.animalSound);
    //                            textView.setText(message);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onBinaryReceived(byte[] data) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPingReceived(byte[] data) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPongReceived(byte[] data) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onException(Exception e) {
            Log.d("WebSocket", "Closed ");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        @Override
        public void onCloseReceived() {
            Log.i("WebSocket", "Closed ");
            System.out.println("onCloseReceived");
        }
    };
    webSocketClient.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    webSocketClient.setReadTimeout(60000);
    webSocketClient.enableAutomaticReconnection(5000);
    webSocketClient.connect();
}
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.client_app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.client_app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'tech.gusavila92:java-android-websocket-client:1.2.2'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

And finally my node server file

```
const express = require('express'); // using express 
const socketIO = require('socket.io'); 
const http = require('http')  
const port = process.env.PORT||8080 // setting the port  
let app = express(); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var router = express.Router(); 

let server = http.createServer(app) 
let io = socketIO(server) 

// make connection with user from server side 
io.on('connection', (socket)=>{ 
console.log('New user connected'); 
 //emit message from server to user 
 socket.emit('newMessage', { 
   from:'jen@mds', 
   text:'hepppp', 
   createdAt:123 
 }); 

// listen for message from user 
socket.on('createMessage', (newMessage)=>{ 
  console.log('newMessage', newMessage); 
}); 

// when server disconnects from user 
socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{ 
  console.log('disconnected from user'); 
}); 
});

io.on('onOpen', (socket)=>{ 
console.log('onOpen-----------'); 

});

app.use('/api', router);
// my local ip
server.listen(port, '192.168.21.133', () => {
console.log("app working", port)
});
```

Comment: Note: I am running this app in AVD emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Your operating system has a localhost, so you can visit http://localhost:8000. But android has a localhost too. So when your app goes to localhost it search for that url in android emulator, you need to go out of there and get into the development computer localhost. What i do is to deploy my node app in a heroku test server and thats it.

Also, as M.Pomeroy says in the comment below, you can access to development machine with the special ip 10.0.2.2, i was missing that information.

Comment: You can access the loopback service of the emulators host computer using the 10.0.2.2 ip alias (source: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html). You can also see in the question he's trying to connect on his router assigned 192.168.X.X address, so localhost routing isn't going to be the issue here.